# How to Determine a property is ComplexType?

Tags: entity-framework

I want to implement an IsComplexType() method, which check if the given property from an entity is a ComplexType.

After reading Entity Framework's source code, i find it has implemented one in the "Helper" class, but the class is "internal", so i can't use it outside Entity Framework project.

I wonder if there's a public API in Entity Framework which enable me to do this. If not, how can i implement it?

Comment: What context do you want to use IsComplexType() from? Are you trying to do this for a code first custom convention in the model, or is this going to be part of the main program?

Comment: @lukew i'm implementing an DatabaseInitializer called "DescriptionInitializer", which read the DescriptionAttribute from the property, and set the descrition to the column which map to the property. With ComplexType, i must go deeper into the type to get the descrition for the column.

Comment: @lukew Another DatabaseInitializer i've implemented is "IndexInitializer", with it, i can use DataAnnotation to create index, and it also need to check the property type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
        var dbContext = new DbContext("ConnectionString");
        var complexType = dbContext.Entry(TEntity).ComplexProperty("ProperyName");
        if (complexType != null)
        {
            // This is a Complex Type
        }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Not working in EF 6.x. When `ComplexProperty("ProperyName")` is called for non-complex property exception is thrown.